# How to describe the correlation between two non-random variable mathematically?

Tags: correlation

As we all know, correlation is a statistical relationship between two random variables. However, if there are two non-random variables, is there correlation between them, if it has, how to describe it  mathematically.

More specially, in random sense, we have $cov\{x,y\}$ to describe the correlation between  two random variables, when it comes to two non-random variables, let's denote them as $x$ and $y$, all of them are bounded by a certain region, for example $x^T P_x x\leq 1$,   $y^T P_y y\leq 1$, ($P_x, P_y$ are available), then, what's the correlation between them?  how to describe it mathematically?

Comment: What are you thinking about when you say "non-random variable"? Because if you're just thinking about two real numbers, $x$ and $y$, there's no meaningful notion of correlation between them.

Comment: When I mentioned  ''two non-random variables'', the true propose is that, for convenience, let's denote them as $x$ and $y$, all of them are bounded by a certain region, for example $x^T P_x x\leq 1$,   $y^T P_y y\leq 1$, then, what's the correlation between them? ($P_x, P_y$ are available)